# addi $s0, $zero, 101

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm learning assembly and am trying to place the number 101 into the $s0 register.

When I run the following line of code:

```
addi $s0, $zero, 101      #$s0 = 0 + 101
```

and then I check the value in $s0 I see,

```
$s1: 00000065
```

What is happening here?

Comment: The `65` is in hex, and that's 101.

Comment: "I check the value in $s0 I see,

`$s1: 00000065`" <-- was that supposed to say `$s0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working correctly.

101 decimal == 0x65 (hex)